# Is it possible to have a lag between scp and checking for new file

Tags: bash, files, scp

Got a cronjob that downloads things regularly:

```
if ! su scpuser -c "scp ..." > /dev/null 2>&1 || ! [ -f $scptarget ]; then;
  error "did not download stuff"
```

`$scptarget` is where the thing gets download to and it's on a different volume than the script that is running (but not a different state, same hard drive I think)

Every time it errors out we go in and look and the file is there.  Is there a chance that the part that checks for the file's existence would succeed if it just chilled out a little bit?  Alternatively, could SCP be tossing errors even when it succeeded?

(I wish the guy who wrote this in the first place would have logged what the actual error was, I'm just kind of grasping at straws)

If so, I don't want to add an arbitrary `sleep` to this script, is there something classier that real bash programmers do?

Comment: Why not log `scp`'s `stderr`? As [Bruce Ediger](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/732/bruce-ediger) says, if you're getting the "did not download stuff" but the file exists it means `scp`'s exit code indicated an error occurred...

Comment: @ste yeah, I'm definitely going to modify the script to do that.  I'm not sure why it wasn't done in the first place. Problem is I'm in the same boat as you guys in trying to figure out why it might not have worked in the past so I can't know for sure if I'm fixing the problem,  I really just want to know what the problems might be.

Answer (score 3):

I did an `strace` on an `scp` of a file.  It looks to me like `scp` does not use a temporary file name like `wget` does, it actually checks for the existence of the destination file, and opens it with `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT`.  The destination file should exist if `scp` gets far to actually have data to write out.

There's no way a "race" between destination file existence and checking on its existence could happen. The shell will have to get SIGCHLD from `scp` exiting to reap the exit status and decide that status is non-zero. I'm pretty sure the kernel would take care of file name existing when the `scp` process exits. File creation is supposed to be atomic. Don't bother to add a `sleep`, it won't help.

The only way your example code will get to the destination file existence test (`[ -f $scptarget ]`) is if `scp` exits with 0 (zero) status. It's certainly possible for the file to exist, yet have an error condition. Do you check the `$scptarget` file for correctness and wholeness when an error occurs? You could be ending up with a partial, or mangled file.

I think that to figure out what's going on, you'd have to use 2 `if` constructs, one for the exit status of `scp`, and the second for the existence of the destination file. Make sure the messages differ, and that you log `$?`, the exit status of the `scp` process.

Answer (score 1):

Get error code first (stderr might be useful too.. Who makes script w/o logging errors...?). It's possible that either 'su' or 'scp' returned retVal>0.

A snip from SCP source code for OSX:

```
 // I'd put my bet for this case..
 void
 lostconn(signo)
    int signo;
 {
    if (!iamremote)
        fprintf(stderr, "lost connection\n");
    exit(1);
 }
```

Make sure that after failure destination file is exactly the same as source file...

Snip from **su** manpage:

> EXIT VALUES
>
> On success, su returns the exit value of the command it executed.
>
> *If this command was terminated by a signal, su returns the number of this signal plus 128.*
>
> If su has to kill the command (because it was asked to terminate, and the command did not terminate in time), su returns 255.

Again.. Without exit code or stderr content there's not much we can do except keep guessing..